# php random number function returning same value each time is called

Tags: php, for-loop, random

I am trying to genarate random number of any length i want to make product id and order id. But the problem here is when i create new item giving the length of the id `11` it will genarte the same id use before it doesn't change the numbers.

Here is my php code

```
<?php
function EventRang($length = 10, $type){
    switch($type){
        case 'int':
        //$keyspace = mt_rand(10000000000, 99999999999).date("Ymd").rand();
        $keyspace = str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $length)-1), $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        break;
        case 'char':
        $keyspace = date('Fl').'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        break;
        case 'str':
        $keyspace = time().'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        break;
        case 'oid':
        //$keyspace = date("Ymd").time().rand().mt_rand(10000000000, 99999999999);
        $keyspace = date("Ymd").time().str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $length)-1), $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        break;
        default:
        $keyspace = time().'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        break;
    }
    $charactersLength = strlen($keyspace);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $keyspace[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
?>
```

this is always the output `2147483647`

Comment: `pow(10,11)` exceeds 32-bit numbers

Comment: `2147483647` is a magic number that you should learn to recognise; it is the max signed int value for 32-bit PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker please help fix it, am new to php that all i can do for now i don't have idea about that magic number

Comment: What characters should be returned for an oid value? You seem to be defining a "mask" rather than a "keyspace", ie a list of valid characters.... possibly better to set the keyspace simply to the list of valid caharacters, and then do any special formatting you might want after generating the random value

Comment: @MarkBaker for `oid` i want to use the current date and time then add random number at the end `date("Ymd").time()4488765`. Please just help me fix it the right way it should be i will have time to look at it and learn more

Comment: So your keyspace should simply be the same as `int`, and then after generating the random number you should prefix it with the date/time (substringing it to a max length if necessary)

Comment: @peterBou : per Mark's suggestions, learning is good. In the absence thereof , next time you see a magic number like `2147483647`, try google. Plenty of enlightening material there for an apprentice.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thank you, i never knew anything like exist, i thought it was my code error or something else

Comment: @MarkBaker are you posting the correct answer for me?

Comment: I'll post it if you can't work it out yourself from my comments

Comment: @MarkBaker am sorry i tried but still can't get it correct, i want to learn from what you will post and also to make sure i avoide having 2 diffrent item with same product id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sometimes answers need to be explicit

```
function EventRang($length = 10, $type = 'int') {
    // Define the set of characters permitted for the random element for each type
    switch($type) {
        case 'int':
        case 'oid':
            $keyspace = '0123456789';
            break;
        case 'char':
            $keyspace = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            break;
        case 'str':
        default:
            $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    }

    // Generate the random characters/digits
    $charactersLength = strlen($keyspace);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $keyspace[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    // apply the masking
    switch($type) {
        case 'int':
            return $randomString;
        case 'char':
            return date('Fl').$randomString;
            break;
        case 'str':
            return time().$randomString;
            break;
        case 'oid':
            return date("Ymd").time().$randomString;
            break;
        default:
            return time().$randomString;
    }
}
```

You need to separate the masking from the keyspace; keyspace is simply the set of characters to use for the random element of the output; if you try to apply the masking as part of the keyspace, you're simply skewing the randomness, and not applying the masking either.

Also note that the function definition needs a default value for type as well, because it comes after length in the argument list, and length has a default value

Comment: The int, is working very fine now but other once return more than the given value. I think i know why because of the making let me try fixing it

Comment: If the value is too long, then substring it before returning.... I didn't know whether you wanted 11 random digits in addition to the masking, or including the masking

Comment: Though I will say that the date masking for `char` is just weird; and a value of 11 for `oid` isn't going to give much variation because `date("Ymd").time()` is already longer than 11